# Canvas method for cutting ImageViews

Tags: android, xml

I am using a RelativeLayout where one ImageView is in the front and the other one in the background. I was using this canvas method to make the front ImageView, half transparent.

```
private Bitmap createTriangleImageTop(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap bmp;

    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap,
            BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP,
            BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    float radius = bitmap.getWidth() / 2f;
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShader(shader);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(bitmap.getWidth()-5, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, bitmap.getHeight()-5);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    return bmp;
}
```

What it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JmAK.jpg

So when I click the ImageView in the background I get the OnclickListener from the ImageView in the front. If I click the ImageView in the front I get, as it should be, the OnClickListener from the front.

I obviously want to be able to click one ImageView and then get the associated OnClickListener, so bringing the BackgroundImageView in the front with bringToFront() doesnt do the job for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is that Android `View`s are rectangular. Even though half of your top image is transparent, it still covers the whole square. So when you "click on the background", you're really clicking on the transparent portion of the foreground.

To get the behavior that you want, change your foreground's click listener to a touch listener, and only trigger your behavior when the user clicks within the opaque area.

```
    foreground.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getX() + event.getY() <= v.getWidth()) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // your code here
                        return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

I'm using `event.getX() + event.getY() <= v.getWidth()` to check if it's in the top-left half of the square; if your foreground layer is slightly different you might need a more complex calculation.

I return `false` in cases where the user clicks in the transparent area, which indicates that the foreground doesn't handle the touch. This allows the touch to go "through" the foreground and be handled by the background.